# some shp to dxf converted lines don't show in Autocad

Tags: qgis, shapefile, convert, autocad, dxf

I have a group of vector files that I intend to convert to "DXF" format. But after the conversion, **only contour lines(white lines in the red polygon) are not displayed in Autocad**. I read some related Q&As in this site but could not get a satisfactory answer. Does the problem stem from the elevation data or intersection with polygon or something different?

Regards[image]

[image]

Comment: What is your shapefiles? Are they polygons or line. Is this shot from CAD or from QGIS. I tend to use Grass for conversions of this kind.

Comment: The problematic shapefile is "line(the contours on red polygon)". The shot is from QGIS.I haven't used grass before

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I defined the datum of contour lines by myself. However it was not defined by CAD programme. So I set the datum same with other vector files and offset the contours. Then I converted to dxf again. As a result, the problem has been solved

Comment: is the 2nd picture the solution??

Comment: No, it isn't the solution. It is the display of the problem. Autocad does not support the "on the fly" like GIS. That was the neglected point

Answer (score 0):

Okay, based on the comments above. I think your first problem is that your white lines are gaps between the polygons.

I would start by establishing what the subject is. I.E. is it lines on a polygon or a polygon with loads of other polygons.

I would try to convert polygons to lines using Vector>Geometry tools>polygons to lines.

If this works and you are no presented with a shapefile of the line, with no red shading, then all is good.

Its a simple matter of conversion to dxf.  you can try right click the file then save as, and select dxf.  this SHOULD work.  However, as i am used to using Grass, as the other method used to not work, i would follow this Video...it is really simple.

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=jmwO9KuoH7A

Comment: I converted the polygon to line however the result isn't changed (I have added the result as image on question part).